# Regex find & replace all spaces with underscore between tags

Tags: regex, replace, sublimetext2

I'm trying to format an xml document before I import it into a database. I have several hundred rows with `<Image #1 File Name>Random string to find and replace</Image #1 File Name>` I have no clue for the life of me on the correct find & replace pattern in regex to do what I need. I was able to match all instances with this:

```
<Image #1 File Name>(.*?)</Image #1 File Name>
```

But I'm unsure on the pattern I need to then replace the whitespace with underscores between the open/close tags `<Image #1 File Name>Random_string_to_find_and_replace</Image #1 File Name>`

Comment: What about the spaces in the tags? You can't have spaces in xml tags like this. That's just not valid xml.

Comment: I'm not worried about validation as this is only being used for importing into a database

Comment: Sublime Text's regex engine doesn't allow you to search/replace things like that, IIRC, as you can't modify the capturing groups.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F'<|>' '{gsub(/ /,"_",$3);print"<"$2">"$3"<"$4">"}' yourxmlfile
```

OK, you can then check with `~` match operator, before filtering:

```
awk -F'<|>' '{if ($0 ~ /Image #1 File Name/) {gsub(/ /,"_",$3);print"<"$2">"$3"<"$4">"} else {print;}}' yourxmlfile
```

Comment: Getting there...I only need certain nodes (<Image #1 File Name>) within the xml file to be replaced. This does every node and also adds <> after each open and close row tag ie. <row><> & </row><>

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the next trick:

1. Replace `<Image #1 File Name>` and `</Image #1 File Name>` with two
   differentspecial words without spaces (example `MY_START_TAG` and
   `MY_END_TAG`).
2. Replace all spaces with underscores.
3. Revert the first step.

Divide and rule :)

Comment: What I'm going to do is import the xml doc into a MySQL database and then do a string replace on those column(s). Should be the easiest pain-free way. Thanks for the input though